# Print the 1st and every nth column of a text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a txt file contains a total of 10177 columns and a total of approximately 450,000 rows. The information is separated by tabs. I am trying to trim the file down using awk so that it only prints the 1-3, 5th, and every 14th column after the fifth one.

My file has a format that looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ... 10177
A B C D E F G H I J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  ...
X Y X Y X Y X Y X Y  X  Y  X  Y  X  Y  X  Y  X  Y  ...
```

I am hoping to generate an output txt file (also separated with tab) that contains:

```
1 2 3 5 18 ...
A B C E R  ...
X Y X X Y  ...
```

The current awk code I have looks like (I am using cygwin to use the code):

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"} { for(i=5;i<10177;i+=14) printf ($i) }' test2.txt > test3.txt
```

But the result I am getting shows something like:

```
123518...ABCER...XYXXY...
```

When opened with excel program, the results are all mashed into 1 single cell.

In addition, when I try to include code

```
for (i=0;i<=3;i++) printf "%s ",$i
```

in the awk to get the first 3 columns, it just prints out the original input document together with the mashed result. I am not familiar with awk, so I am not sure what causes this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk field numbers, strings, and array indices all start at 1, not 0, so when you do:

```
for (i=0;i<=3;i++) printf "%s ",$i
```

the first iteration prints `$0` which is the whole record.

You're on the right track with:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"} { for(i=5;i<10177;i+=14) printf ($i) }' test2.txt > test3.txt
```

but never do printf with input data as the only argument to printf since then printf will treat it as a format string without data (rather than what you want which is a plain string format with your data) and then that will fail cryptically if/when your input data contains formatting characters like `%s` or `%d`. So, always use `printf "%s", $i`, never `printf $i`.

The problem you're having with excel, I would guess, is you're trying to double click on the file and hoping excel knows what to do with it (it won't, unlike if this was a CSV). You can import tab-separated files into excel after it's opened though - google that.

You want something like:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), $i
        }
        for (i=5; i<=NF; i+=14) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
        }
        print ""
    }
' file
```

I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

In awk using conditional operator in `for`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
       {
           for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=( i<3 ? 1 : ( i==3 ? 2 : 14 )))
               printf "%s%s", $i, ( (i+14)>NF ? ORS : OFS)
       }' file
1 2 3 5 19
A B C E S
X Y X X X
```

In the `for` if `i<3` increment by one, if `i==3` increment by two to get to 5 and after that by 14.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to solve the problem along the following lines.  I think you'll find you save time by not iterating in awk.

```
$ cols="$( { echo 1 2 3; seq 5 14 10177; } | sed 's/^/$/; 2,$ s/^/, /' )"
$ awk -F\\t "{print $cols}" test.txt
```